# What does this divide and conquer algorithm do?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm sure this is fairly simple, which is why I'm very frustrated. I got this code on an interview, and I was asked about what the code computes, and what the complexity is. I'm still confused. I tried writing down outputs as bases of 2, but I still did not find a pattern. This is the code:

```
def mystery(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  if n % 2 == 0:
    return mystery(n/2)
  else:
    return mystery(2(n-1)) + 1
```

I know that the second line is testing for when it is even, however, I still don't understand what this function does overall. Any ideas?
**edit: changed A to mystery.

Comment: The algorithm would be much more clear if the last line was `return mystery ((n -1) / 2) + 1`.  Although this happens to yield the same values, it's less direct, and it doesn't make clear what the step represents.  It seems obfuscation for its own sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `A`s are supposed to be recursive calls to `mystery`, then:

This is not really a divide and conquer algorithm.  It just returns the number of 1 bits in the binary representation of `n`, in a somewhat roundabout way.

It's easier to understand if you walk through what happens when `n` is odd.  Then `n` = `2x+1` for some `x`, and `mystery(n)` = `mystery(4x)+1` = `mystery(2x)+1` = `mystery(x)+1` = `mystery(floor(n/2))+1`

Comment: Does that mean that this is O(n)?

Comment: Each recursive step reduces the size of the input by half, so this is actually `O(n)`: For any positive integer, this creates one call for digit in the binary representation of the number.

Comment: @oryx gotta be careful here.  It's O(log `n`), where `n` is the parameter to the function, or O(N), where 'N' is the size of the input.